# Removing a text field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, textfield

I have the following code to add text fields when the function is called:

```
<span id="response"></span>
        <script>
        var qcountBox = 2;
        var acountBox = 2;
        var qboxName = 0;
        var aboxName = 0;
        function addInput()
        {
             var qboxName="question"+qcountBox;
             var aboxName="answer"+acountBox;
             if(qcountBox <=10 && acountBox <= 10) 
                {
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<br/>Question '+qcountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+qboxName+'"/>';
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<br/>Answer '+acountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+aboxName+'"/><br/>';
                qcountBox ++;
                acountBox ++;
             }else
             alert("No more than 10 questions allowed at this time.");
        }
```

I also would like to be able to add a function to remove any new fields I have added. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: while adding the questions use specific id for a div and add your questions in it then it 'll be easy to remove that div completely using the id

Answer (score 0):

Surround each new piece of HTML in a span with a common class name.  Then, find all the objects with that class name and remove them.

Add the span and class name to these:

```
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<span class="added"> <br/>Question '+qcountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+qboxName+'"/></span>';
document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<span class="added"><br/>Answer '+acountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+aboxName+'"/><br/></span>';
```

Then, you can remove all the added spans like this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("added");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].parentNode.removeChild(items[i]);
}
```

Note: This is a generally better way to add your new HTML as it doesn't rewrite all previous HTML - it just adds new DOM objects:

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "added";
span.innerHTML = '<br/>Question '+qcountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+qboxName+'"/><br/>Answer '+acountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+aboxName+'"/><br/>';
document.getElementById('response').appendChild(span);
```

Comment: I have a span I forgot to include that part of the code, I just updated it. How can I use what you posted as a button? Thanks

Comment: You create a button, attach a click handler that executes the code for removing the added questions.

Comment: seems i hit someones soft spot

Comment: @MattI - I edited my previous comment before your remarks.  But, I was feeling like you need to do a little research here yourself to at least find out how to hook up javascript to a button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var qcountBox = 1;
        var acountBox = 1;
        var qboxName = 0;
        var aboxName = 0;
        function addInput()
        {
             var qboxName="question"+qcountBox;
             var aboxName="answer"+acountBox;
             if(qcountBox <=10 && acountBox <= 10) 
                {
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<div id="'+qcountBox+'"><br/>Question '+qcountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+qboxName+'"/>';
                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML+='<br/>Answer '+acountBox+': <input type="text" name="'+aboxName+'"/><br/></div>';
                qcountBox ++;
                acountBox ++;
             }else
             alert("No more than 10 questions allowed at this time.");
        }
        function removeInput(id)
        {
             document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
        }
```

You can remove any question that you added using the id of the question div (same as qboxName)

Answer (score 0):

You should actually create an input element in javascript and append it to your container through `appendChild` instead of using `innerHTML +=`.

You should also set an ID for those fields, not just a name. But it can be the same as theirs names.

Like this

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = input.id = qboxName;
document.getElementById("response").appendChild(input);
```

And then, you know, do the same for the other input field you need.
I know you need a text label for the boxes, or whatever, just do the same process to insert a span tag before them.

Also, I don't see a reason for those two counting variables. Instead of `qcountBox` and `acountBox` it's totally possible to have only one single counting variable. Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't you increase this counting before setting the boxes names?

As for removing it, you can use the `removeChild` method, then, decrease your counting variable. like this:

```
function removeInput()
{
    var qboxName = "question" + count;
    var aboxName = "answer" + count;
    document.getElementById("response").removeChild(document.getElementById(aboxName));
    document.getElementById("response").removeChild(document.getElementById(aboxName));
    count--;
}
```

Maybe if you're going to insert other elements together with these fields, like span tags for labels etc, it would be better to wrap them all up in a div or something, then simply do a `removeChild` to this container div only.